# png terminal in gnuplot finds fonts but not symbols (like greek letters)

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to make some png figures with gnuplot because I can tex them quickly into a draft and they are much smaller than the similar eps or pdf figures (and so don't freeze my tex environment).  However I am having trouble getting greek letters to come out in the png terminal.  Otherwise the png figures look fine and they are so much faster to work with!

I am running gnuplot Version 4.4 patchlevel 3 on snow leopard on a mac.
I have this in my .profile

```
export GDFONTPATH=/Library/Fonts/
```

so that the gnuplot png terminal can find my fonts.

The error I get is this:

> gdImageStringFT: No character set found while printing string a with font Symbol

I am using

```
 set term png enhanced
```

Undercores and exponents work fine  like

```
set xlabel "x_2".
```

I tried a bunch of different fonts -- they all look fine, just the symbols don't show up.
For example

```
set xlabel "{/Symbol a}"
```

gives the error above for gd

I did manage to get some unicode to display on a png terminal but can't figure out how to choose the characters in a text file (apparently I can only cut and past them in and there is no other way to choose them?).

I could go back to pdf or eps and convert to something smaller so my tex manuscript is not swamped by slow large figures.

Suggestions for a fix would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure this question is relevant to TeX.sx. I am also not entirely certain how your pdf outputs can be so much bigger than png outputs. eps will indeed be much larger that pdf but the pdf should be fairly small unless you are talking about very complex figures. Anyway, 4.4 and the newer 4.6 version has the cairo based outputs (pngcairo, pdfcairo,...) which should have better compatibility with fonts (however I do not know if these are available in the OS X version.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I don't see what's the issue with the question. It is clearly TeX related, and the FAQ cites "Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc." as scope of the site.

Comment: Thanks Peter Grill your edit will help me better edit my future posts!

Comment: ARTourter Upgrading to gnuplot 4.6 and using the terminal pngcairo fixes the problem!  As you suggested.  Thanks!